# opencart voucher, extra link seems to interrupt onclick

Tags: php, javascript, html, opencart

In the vouchers list in opencart, it checks to see if there are vouchers and then displays them, you can then officially send the voucer by clicking "Send". For some reason, this process only seems to work if I remove the link `<a>` tag straight after this send option. I cannot figure out why.
Here is the list...

```
           <?php foreach ($vouchers as $voucher) { ?>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align: center;"><?php if ($voucher['selected']) { ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="<?php echo $voucher['voucher_id']; ?>" checked="checked" />
            <?php } else { ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="<?php echo $voucher['voucher_id']; ?>" />
            <?php } ?></td>
          <td class="left"><?php echo $voucher['code']; ?></td>
          <td class="left"><?php echo $voucher['from']; ?></td>
          <td class="left"><?php echo $voucher['to']; ?></td>
          <td class="right"><?php echo $voucher['amount']; ?></td>
          <td class="left"><?php echo $voucher['theme']; ?></td>
          <td class="left"><?php echo $voucher['status']; ?></td>
          <td class="left"><?php echo $voucher['date_added']; ?></td>
          <td class="right">[ <a onclick="sendVoucher('<?php echo $voucher['voucher_id']; ?>');"><?php echo $text_send; ?></a> ]
            <?php foreach ($voucher['action'] as $action) { ?>
            [ <a href="<?php echo $action['href']; ?>"><?php echo $action['text']; ?></a> ]
            <?php } ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
```

In the code above when I remove the second `<a href="<?php echo $action['href']; ?>"><?php echo $action['text']; ?></a>`, the `onclick` works as it should, when I dont remove it, instead of sending the voucher, it simply takes me to editing area of that voucher.

Heres the `sendVoucher` function, however Im not even sure if that function is related to the problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
 function sendVoucher(voucher_id) {
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=sale/voucher/send&token=<?php echo $token;       ?>&voucher_id=' + voucher_id,
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('.success, .warning').remove();
        $('.box').before('<div class="attention"><img src="view/image       /loading.gif" alt="" /> <?php echo $text_wait; ?></div>');
    },
    complete: function() {
        $('.attention').remove();
    },
    success: function(json) {
        if (json['error']) {
            $('.box').before('<div class="warning">' + json['error'] + '</div>');
        }

        if (json['success']) {
            $('.box').before('<div class="success">' + json['success'] + '</div>');
        }       
    }
});
    return false;
  }
  //--></script>
```

EDIT: For more clarity, heres the output html of a row...

```
                      <tr>
          <td style="text-align: center;">                <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="4" />
            </td>
          <td class="left">34123123</td>
          <td class="left">adrian</td>
          <td class="left">Adrian</td>
          <td class="right">€20.00</td>
          <td class="left">Birthday</td>
          <td class="left">Enabled</td>
          <td class="left">07/02/2013</td>
          <td class="right">[ <a onclick="sendVoucher('4');"  >Send</a> ]
                            [ <a href="http://mysite.com/admin/index.php?route=sale/voucher/update&amp;token=c9b6332af21513c0a3af8e4265fa62a1&amp;voucher_id=4">Edit</a> ] 
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Just try adding an `href="#"` in that first one, also `return false;` at the end of `sendVoucher()`.

Comment: thanks but unfortunately that didnt work, that just takes me back to the log in page as the url its picking up is  mysite.com/admin/#

Comment: did you do `return false;` at the end of `sendVoucher()` ? Not inside `$.ajax()`.

Comment: yep! Ive edited the code to show you where...For some reason it insists on going straight to the following link unless its removed.

Comment: One more thing, could you copy-paste that row's html alone? I meant, copy-paste the page source via browser.

Comment: Ive included it at the end, thanks

Comment: Now, the only reason I can think of is, there's some kind of error in that js function, hence it's not returning `false` and you are being redirected. Also, make sure if you are reaching the function, by adding an `alert("Hi");` or `console.log("hi");`.

Also, I do not see that `href="#"` in your output.

Comment: thanks for the help, Ill look again within the function, I removed the `href="#"` again just to be consistent with the original question as when that is in there the link doesnt work at all (takes me back to the admin login), but ill implement it again after looking at the js function thanks for the help!

Comment: anchor tag without `href` is invalid, don't remove/ignore that.

Comment: ok thanks its back in, the `alert` appears in the `beforesend` function, but stops appearing after that, so its not completing and simply taking me back to the log in page.

Comment: hmm, try attaching `.done(function(data) { alert(data); });` at the end of your `$.ajax();`.

Comment: that gives me an error unfortunately ... `SyntaxError: missing } after property list [Break On This Error] .done(function(data) { alert(data); });`

Comment: Umm, where did you attach it?
`$.ajax({}).done(function(){});` like this? outside the `$.ajax()` right?

Comment: yes but unfortunately still behaving the exact same way. Im wondering might there be an issue with the url in `ajax` thats causing it to fail.